# Taking screenshots of desktop from a web application

Tags: screenshot, fullscreen, web

I am trying to convert one of my earlier written time tracking apps to a web browser based app.

Some options of technology include java, flash, ... My goal here is letting a user track time for our organization while having ideally no extra installation on desktop, or least minimal, like flashplayer or jvm, etc, but the product itself should be in browser.

I have done some research and so far i can't find a way any technology, of the ones i have known, could take a screenshot of whole desktop while running inside web browser even if, say, browser is out of focus.

The best i could do was take a screenshot of the page on which that app will run. Any ideas? Possible? leads?

Comment: Perhaps not yet a practical solution, but still an interesting project you may find relevant: https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/getusermedia/screenshare.html